# Npm is ignoring dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I decided to move my project into different folder. I didn't copy the node-modules folder.

When I run npm install, it said nothing and installed nothing. Obviously it looked into devDependencies section instead of Dependencies that I used before.

How can I make npm install all from Dependencies?

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "zzz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "^1.4.1",
    "grunt-exec": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-link-html": "^0.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.0-rc1",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
}
```

If I try to install package individually it creates and updates devDependencies section, not dependencies as expected.

Solution found. It turned out that NPM stops working as expected if you have spaces in the "name" in package.json. As soon as I removed them NPM started working. It was so confusing!

Comment: What's your package.json look like and where is it located?

Comment: @Paul, it looks normally and located in the same folder where is grunt. I'm running npm install exactly from that folder. Let me update my question. The problem is NPM is ignoring dependencies section, I don't know WHY?

Comment: If you're in a folder with a package.json (regardless of how you've installed grunt; I'm not sure why you bring that up), npm will install all the dependencies (and devDependencies unless you add --production) to the `./node_modules` folder.  If it's not working, then one of the things I just said isn't true.

Comment: @Paul, I mentioned grunt because I firstly thought it's problem with it. Now I see it's problem with NPM. I'm in folder with package.json and NPM completely ignoring all in dependencies section. It even doesn't create node_modules. For some reason it looks only for *devDependencies* - can you explain me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Try to move it to a folder located on desktop and then run `npm install` again. Some times it happens because of the length of the path.

Comment: @AlqamaBinSadiq I tried in another folder with a short name, the same result. It just created package-lock.json file but didn't install anything and didn't create node_modules folder. Why does it ignore dependencies?

Comment: You should also check to make sure the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) isn't set to only install dev (--only=dev or via the npmrc or environment variables)

Comment: @mimic Did you move all of your files to a folder located at Desktop?

Comment: I figured it out. I can't believe. The problem was I had a space in the name in package.json. As soon as I removed it NPM started working. Thanks everyone for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your json in the form of a blank space near `"serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"`. Better use an IDE like VSCODE and an extension like beautify to avoid unnecessary errors.Also its asking for a dependency `"grunt@~0.4.0"` . So install it and do `npm install`.